# images on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, iphone, sencha-touch

Hello I hope someone can help. I am creating an application that allows people to browse and download images. I know I can't access the photo library from mobile safari, my question is how can I deliver the images to a user? I don't think I can access mobile browsers copy > clipboard with javascript, can I? I am using sencha touch and it seems very difficult to implement press > hold > copy. Any ideas how you would deliver say 20 images to someone through the phone through mobile browser?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could email them to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just display the images and then they can download them to their photo library? On an iphone you just hold down over an image and a sheet will popup asking the user if they want to save an image.

Comment: I think that maybe the only way but I am using sencha touch, I guess the question is what is the best way to implement this with sencha. I have the image display out of the application